# Local Notification repetation at different times

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an app that generates prayer times (5 times a day) i want to create notfication for the 5 prayers but the issue is the times change everyday based on some calculations.

**Edit:**

The calculations are done based on GPS location so when the user changes to another city the times will be updated accordingly. I input the date,timezone, GPS coordinates into a method and I get prayer time values in (HH:mm) format for that given day/location. Now I need to setup the Notfications. I'm not sure where to set them up.

here is the code

```
#import "PrayerTimeViewController.h"
#import "PrayTime.h"

@implementation PrayerTimeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
        [tbi setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"PrayerTimes", nil)];
        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11-clock"];

        [tbi setImage:i];
        [i release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Madinah"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (t < -180) {
        return;
    }

    PrayTime *prayerTime = [[PrayTime alloc]init];
    [prayerTime setCalcMethod:0];
    [prayerTime setFajrAngle:16];
    [prayerTime setIshaAngle:14];
    [prayerTime setAsrMethod:0];



    NSDate *curentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* compoNents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:curentDate];     
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currLoc = [newLocation coordinate];


    NSMutableArray *prayerCal = [prayerTime getDatePrayerTimes:[compoNents year]  andMonth:[compoNents month] andDay:[compoNents day] andLatitude:currLoc.latitude andLongitude:currLoc.longitude andtimeZone:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]/3600];
    [prayerTime release];

    [fajer setText:[prayerCal objectAtIndex:0]];
//    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSString *time = [prayerCal objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d %@",[compoNents year],[compoNents month],[compoNents day],time];


    NSDateFormatter *dateText = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateText setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    [dateText setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]]];

    NSLog(@"%@",[dateText dateFromString:dates]);

    [shrooq setText:[prayerCal objectAtIndex:1]];

    [duhur setText:[prayerCal objectAtIndex:2]];

    [aser setText:[prayerCal objectAtIndex:3]];

    [maghreb setText:[prayerCal objectAtIndex:5]];

    [isha setText:[prayerCal objectAtIndex:6]];

    [prayerCal release];

}



@end
```

Comment: Show some code (i.e. the calculations)

Comment: just add 5 notifications

Comment: Is the question how to calculate the times, or how to schedule the `UILocalNotification`s?

Comment: Its how to create the notifications. I can create the notfications but insure on how to renew the notfication for the next days even if the user doesnt access my app

Comment: Hi @M7ammed, did you figure a simple/good way to implement this task. I'm having the same issue and the answer below doesn't work properly (*The GPS solution will is not battery efficient*). Could you provide your solution or a snippet of code that makes it work. Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `repeatInterval` parameter to repeat your five notifications, making them appear at the same time every day. Unfortunately there's no way to adjust the time without running your app.

You *can* run a GPS app in the background, though that would be quite a drain on the battery just for setting some timers. (This background process is really designed for GPS tracker apps. I'm not sure what Apple would make of using it for a slightly different purpose.)

But the easiest way would be just to update when the app is launched. When it launches you would get the current notifications (using the `scheduledLocalNotifications` property of `UIApplication`), cancel them if they're incorrect or out of date and create new ones. Each notification has a dictionary payload that you can use to make it easier to identify your alarms.

Comment: The problem is these time are not consestant for example one day it will be 4:30 next 4:32 and after a month it will increase more and then at some point in the year it will decrease it is related to sunrise and sunset and postionin of the sun hence the daily changes.

Comment: I refer you to my final paragraph. In iOS there's no way to run arbitrary apps in the background. Alternatively you might consider push notification (i.e., from a server), but you'd use the change in GPS to tell the server where the phone is. There might be privacy considerations with that, of course.

Comment: Ok so I would update it evertime the app is launched, so I should setup the notification in the view did Load? How can I make sure not to set the notfication everytime  the user entrers the app? Wont there be a notification already set ?

Comment: Thanks :) will give it ago seems like the only way to go