# How to set Local Notification repeat interval on Prayer time everyday different times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In local notifications there is repeatInterval property where we can put the unit repeat intervals for minute, hour, day, week, year, etc.

I want that repeat interval on Prayer time hours and every day same process.

So every Prayer time hours the local notification comes.

Prayer time is everyday different times

How do I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest to create a local notification for each praying hour in a day with a repeat interval of 1 day.

Comment: @Larme, as far as I know, prayer time varies from day to day, as at least some of them are based on sunset/sunrise and the like.

Comment: @jcaron you are right

Comment: @Larme prayers time will change on every day

Comment: You can find the calculations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salah_times#Time_calculation

Comment: @jcaron i have already Salah times

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700890/how-to-repeat-local-notifications-every-day-at-different-times

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this :

```
NSCalendar *calen = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *components = [calen components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setHour:9];
[components setMinute:30];
[components setSecond:00];

UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notif.fireDate = [calen dateFromComponents:components];
notif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
[notif setAlertBody:@"Its prayer time..."];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: but every day time is different and schedule every day

Comment: Yes and already i have prayer time calculation method. and also get times as well

Comment: every day different times?

Comment: May be you should use two local Notifications to achieve that. One notification for everyday, and upon receiving the day-wise notification in the handling method you may get prayer times for that day and register for another notification for those particular time intervals.

Comment: @iOSGeek i suggested the same

Comment: Oh yes, now i checked that you explained the same thing in chat.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700890/how-to-repeat-local-notifications-every-day-at-different-times